# Kähler differentials on $C^\infty(S^1)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, differential-forms, noncommutative-geometry

I'm trying to learn a bit about "de Rham homology" for algebras. Let us take $A=C^\infty(S^1)$.

So if I understand well, the complex given by Kähler differentials and $d$ should compute de Rham cohomology of the circle.

But I don't quite see what would be the representative for the generator "$d\theta$" in degree 1. Since $\theta$ is not a function I am a little confused as to what should be the element in $\Omega^1_A$ representing that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While $\theta$ only exists as a "multivalued function", there is still a sense in which this analytic, and we can compute its differential. E.g. considering $S^1$ as the unit circle in the punctured plane, from

$$ \tan(\theta) = \frac{y}{x} $$

we compute

$$ \sec(\theta)^2 \mathrm{d} \theta = \frac{x \mathrm{d}y - y \mathrm{d} x}{x^2} $$
$$ \sec(\theta)^2 = 1 + \tan(\theta)^2 = \frac{x^2 + y^2}{x^2} $$

and thus

$$ \mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{x \mathrm{d}y - y \mathrm{d} x}{x^2 + y^2} $$

This last formula is a well-defined differential form, and has exactly the properties we'd want from $\mathrm{d} \theta$.

---

I should remark that for this ring, the module of Kähler differentials $\Omega^1_{A/\mathbb{R}}$ is uncomfortable to work with, and may be a bad idea to think deeply upon if your interests are more along the lines of algebraic geometry.

In particular, while there is a relationship with classical differential forms, they aren't the same thing. See [this old (unanswered) question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248595/are-k%C3%A4hler-differentials-the-same-as-one-forms-for-compact-manifolds), as well as the posts it links to.

The module $\Omega^1_{A}$ of absolute differentials would be even worse to consider, since it will contain all of the weird features of $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: @vap: Well, you still need to restrict the differential forms to the circle, but I presumed you'd have a better time understanding how to interpret $x$ as a function on the circle and its differential $\mathrm{d}x$ as a differential form on the circle. Note, incidentally, that $\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}y$ are not independent when restricted to the circle; they satisfy a relation $x \mathrm{d}x + y \mathrm{d}y = 0$.

Comment: so I guess your answer is that there is an inclusion $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2=1)\to A$ and the element I want is the image via this inclusion of the form you wrote. I'd like to see something more explicit but I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: @vap: Or just take the function given by $x$ (and so forth); it's a function on the circle too, by restriction. You have to write down functions on the circle in *some* fashion; I don't think you can get away from that. I'm honestly not sure in what sense you think the formula I ultimately conclude is not explicit.

Comment: Right, so the element $\omega\in\Omega^1_A$ I want is $\omega=xdy-ydx$. Now $d\omega= dxdy-dydx$, how can I see this is zero algebraically?

Comment: @vap: There are a few options. On the domain $x \neq 0$ you can solve $\mathrm{d}x = -\frac{y}{x} \mathrm{d}y$ and so $d\omega$ vanishes on that domain. Similarly on the $y \neq 0$ domain. Since these cover everything, $d\omega$ vanishes everywhere.

Comment: @vap: Another is that $x \mathrm{d}\omega = 0$ because you can substitute $x \mathrm{d}x = -y \mathrm{d}y$, and $y \mathrm{d}\omega = 0$ for a similar reason. Thus $(x^2 + y^2) \mathrm{d}\omega = 0$ too.

Comment: @vap: Thirdly, you could invoke a theorem that for any smooth one-dimensional manifold, $\Omega^2 = 0$. Since $\mathrm{d}\omega$ is a member of that space, $\mathrm{d}\omega = 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies. I understand methods 1 and 3 but I can't follow your second, which I like because it is completely algebraic. Can you please expand on it? Thanks.

Comment: @vap: Which part of it? I guess I'll expand the whole thing. The taking the differential of the identity $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ gives the identity $2 x \mathrm{d}x + 2 y \mathrm{d}y = 0$. Thus, $x \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y = (-y \mathrm{d}y) \mathrm{d}y = 0$ and $y \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y = -(y \mathrm{d}y) \mathrm{d}x = x \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}x = 0$. Then $(x^2 + y^2)\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y = x (x \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d}y) + y (y \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y) = x0 + y0 = 0$.

Comment: @vap: As an aside, I was mislead by your consideration of $C^{\infty}(S^1)$, since it put me mentally in the realm of differential geometry. There is a relationship between Kahler differentials and covector fields, but they might not actually be the same thing. See [this unanswered question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248595/are-k%C3%A4hler-differentials-the-same-as-one-forms-for-compact-manifolds) and the other posts it links to. I think everything I've said is still true (except possibly for $\Omega^2 = 0$), precisely because it *is* rather algebraic.

Comment: To expand on my worry, the point is that I'm not sure $\{ \mathrm{d}x, \mathrm{d}y \}$ span the module $\Omega^1$, and all of my intuition follows from that premise.

Comment: @vap: (and I'm definitely assuming you're asking for the relative differentials over $\mathbb{R}$, not the absolute differentials over $\mathbb{Z}$)

Comment: I wrote something on your unanswered question.